# Android NDK clang compiler can't find std::make_unique

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, clang, c++14

I'm using Android NDK r10d. My application.mk is setup like so:

```
APP_CFLAGS := -DANDROID -DBUILD_OGLES2
APP_CPPFLAGS := $(APP_CFLAGS) -fexceptions -frtti -std=c++14
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-15
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
```

I am using `std::make_unique` in my code and it isn't compiling (says it isn't found). This feature should be available in STL starting with C++14. I did some poking around and it seems that clang isn't using GNU STL 4.9 in the NDK. If it were, it would be available since I see it inside `<memory>` header.

What am I missing here? Is there a way to use 4.9 GNU STL with clang?

Comment: Try adding `-stdlib=libstdc++` to `APP_CPPFLAGS`

Comment: @Praetorian Still didn't work :-( `error: no member named 'make_unique' in namespace 'std'`

Comment: You could grab an implementation of `make_unique` [elsewhere](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3656.txt) in the meantime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make_unique` isn't available through gnustl from clang. You can try using LLVM libc++ instead. Set this inside your *Application.mk*:

```
APP_STL := c++_static
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
```

edit:
Forcing the use of GNU STL 4.9 (by changing TOOLCHAIN_VERSION inside `android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/*toolchain_name*-clang3.5/setup.mk`) makes the build crash:

`clang++: /s/ndk-toolchain/src/llvm-3.5/llvm/tools/clang/lib/AST/DeclBase.cpp:1293: clang::DeclContext::lookup_result clang::DeclContext::lookup(clang::DeclarationName): Assertion 'DeclKind != Decl::LinkageSpec && "Should not perform lookups into linkage specs!"' failed.`

Comment: Yes it is available in tool chain version 4.9.

Comment: but clang relies on gcc 4.8 and making it switch to 4.9 doesn't work, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks. I had this problem with 'unique_ptr' and switching from 'stlport_shared' to 'c++_shared' seems to have fixed it.